# Textfield : Some text editable some text static in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I am trying to do a task....I have a `textfield` which have value + unit (like: 20 cm), when user click on `textfield` only value will update and unit text is as it is. This means in any case user not able to remove unit from the `textfield` on click. How to do this?
Please anybody suggest me the proper way.

Comment: Two solutions:1.Cheat,make up a fake text field. 2.Customize,you can replace string when text changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `UILabel` as a rightView in `UITextField`.

eg.

```
UILabel *unit = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
unit.text = @"cm";

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init...];
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
textField.leftView = unit;
```

and you can implement `UITextField`'s delegate method to manage leftView as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do code something like below. Make label as `rightView` of 
`UITextField`.

```
rightViewMode  = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
UILabel *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)];

view.text = @"Rs" // Your unit set as text of `UILabel`
textfield.rightView = view;
```